# find the N closest rows in another table without using lateral join

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables and I need to find the rows from the second one which are closest to the ones in the first table, measured by some easy-to-compute metric, e.g. the two closest rows measured by difference.

Starting with

```
create table t1 (id int, name text, x int);
create table t2 (id int, name text, x int);
insert into t1 values (1, 'foo', 10), (2, 'bar', 3);
insert into t2 values (1, 'a', 10), (2, 'b', 11), (1, 'c', 7);
```

I want to get to something like

| name | name |
| --- | --- |
| foo | a |
| foo | b |
| bar | c |
| bar | a |

since the values of rows `a` and `b` in `t2` (10 and 11, respectively) are the two closest rows to the value of `foo` in `t1`.

Following [this advice](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/100828/converting-outer-apply-with-correlated-subquery-in-sql-server-to-sqlite/100850#100850), I tried

```
select *
from t1
left join t2
on t2.id = (
  select id
  from t2
  where t2.id==t1.id
  order by abs(t2.x-t1.x) desc
  limit 2)
```

That does not work: I get the error `no such column t1.x`. (Mind you, this query works if I order by something more straightforward in the subquery, such as `name`, as it was suggested by the original poster).

I am guessing I could use lateral join in PostgreSQL for this [(as it was suggested here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65065928/find-closest-match-to-value-in-another-table), but for now it seems I am constrained to sqlite.

Comment: What are the volumes (number of rows) of your two tables t1 and t2?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to compute the cartesian product of your two tables, then extract the first two matching rows for each "*t1.x*" value that have the least difference of
values with respect to "*t2.x*":

- the cartesian product is obtained using `1=1` inside the `ON` condition (which is always true for each combination of t1 row and t2 row)
- getting the first matching rows is obtained by ordering on your ranking value (computed with `ROW_NUMBER`) and limiting the number of rows to the amount of t1 rows multiplied by 2 (the first two t2 rows for each t1 row).

```
SELECT t1.name AS namet1,
       t2.name AS namet2
FROM       t1
INNER JOIN t2 
        ON 1=1 
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t1.id ORDER BY ABS(t1.x-t2.x))
LIMIT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t1) *2
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/94DrrCmGy7sQBPtS2N4G6z/1).

Note: this solution is somewhat expensive given that it involves a cartesian product, yet *there may be* no other solution to check for the minimum value of a table with respect to another table other than checking the difference between the each value of the first table for each value of the second table.